# Using `exist` with structure array

Tags: matlab, struct

The assignment is

> You are testing a functional near infrared (fNIR) device and 
>   measuring how well each subject is able to control the computer mouse using 
>   it. Write a function `getcogdata` that returns the requested category for 
>   the requested user id. If the requested user does not exist, return an empty 
>   matrix. If no user is requested, return a
>   cell array of values for all users.

My code is as follows

```
function output=getcogdata(cat,id)
info=struct('id',{'33','10','48','41'},'name',{'Joe','Sally','Harry','Ann'},...
    'age',{'27','25','23','19'},...
    'height',{'5.9','6.1','5.8','6.0'},'score',{'9,5','9.3','9.7','9.4'});
if id=='33'
    id=1;
elseif id=='10'
    id=2;
elseif id=='48'
    id=3;
else id=='41'
    id=4;
end
output=info(id).(cat)
end
```

My code works for when measurement and user are specified but I can't figure out how to code for if the user doesn't exist or if no user is requested. I tried not `exist(id)` I get an error. Is there a way I can use not exist?

Comment: Search for Matlab null comparison to check for a null id.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab's [`exist`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) function will tell you if *something* is **known** to the current Matlab instance. It **won't** tell you if a particular value is present.

---

Your task is probably a little bit more complex than you originally thought but you can accomplish it with a mixture of [`strcmp`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html), and [`any`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html).

First, we convert the `id`s in `info` to a cell array with

```
{info.id}
```

now we can use [`strcmp`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) to compare them against `id`

```
strcmp(id, {info.id})
```

Finally, we can use [`any`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) to tell us if any of the values in `{info.id}` are equal to `id`. So putting this all together we get

```
>> info = struct('id',{'33','10','48','41'});
>> id = '33';
>> any(strcmp(id, {info.id}))
ans =
     1
```

---

We can also this to find the index of `id` in `{info.id}` and do away with the `if` statements in your question by using [`find`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) instead of [`any`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html)

```
>> id = '10'; % Present in index 2 - Output should be 2
>> find(strcmp(id, {info.id}))
ans =
     2
```

---

To answer your final question about not passing the `id` to `getcogdata` you can do this using [`nargin`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html)

```
function output = getcogdata(cat,id)
    if (nargin < 2)
        fprintf(1, 'No id passed to getcogdata()\n');
    end
end
```

[`nargin`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) will tell you how many arguments were passed to the function `getcogdata`.

---

Thanks to @[AndrasDeak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067311/andras-deak) for teaching me Matlab's `strcmp` is much better than the C version I had been assuming it was similar to!

Note: **Always read the manual!**

Comment: `strcmp` has the really cool attribute to work over cells: you can just do `find(strcmp(id,info.id))`.

Comment: `ismember({info.id}, id)` will work too, you need the `{}` brackets. I'm just on a bit of a `cellfun` buzz at the moment though!

Comment: The bracket thing's a bit weird, from the definition I'd think that `info.id` is a cell itself. But I suspected that you bracket it for a reason:)

Comment: I didn't know that about `strcmp`. I've just always used it like the C function. I'll update the answer with just that instead. Thanks ;) The brackets are needed because its a `1x4` **struct** so what is returned is 4 separate answers (char arrays). The easiest way to concatenate (grab them all) is with `{}`.

Comment: Aaah, I see. So basically the result is implied to have `{:}`. I didn't know that, thanks:) Guess we're even;)

Comment: Yeah that's it exactly. I wasn't sure my explanation made sense but I'm glad you got it. I guess we are ;)